# deque iterator not dereferencable error in debug mode

Tags: c++, iterator, dereference, deque

Need a bit of help from you.
I am writing an application for c++ having the use of queue STL container in my code.
While accessing the front() element of that queue, I am encountering a "deque iterator not dereferencable" error. This specific error is coming in debug mode only.

The code is below.

---

```
// haraldMsgDb is a queue of strings declared in header file
// std::queue <std::string> haraldMsgDb;

    void handle_message(Message& message)
    {
        std::string dataString = "\"" + std::string(message.getName()) + "\":" + std::string("#") + "\"" + std::string(message.getTime().toString()) + "\"" + std::string(":") + "\"" + std::string(message.getData()) + "\"";
        /* pushing data in queue here*/
        App::Instance->haraldMsgDb.push(dataString);  
    }

/*fetching the queue data in this function*/

    void SendData()
    {
        /*Some stuff*/
        while (1)
        {
            while (!TimeSeriesApp::TimeSeriesAppInstance->haraldMsgDb.empty())
            {
                if (data.length() < 3000)
                {
                    data += App::Instance->haraldMsgDb.front();  // ---->>> getting the "deque iterator not dereferencable" error here, somtimes the error comes in below line as well
                    std::string key = App::Instance->haraldMsgDb.front().substr(0, App::Instance->haraldMsgDb.front().find("#"));
                    std::string value = App::Instance->haraldMsgDb.front().substr(App::Instance->haraldMsgDb.front().find("#") + 1, std::string::npos);

                    App::Instance->haraldMsgDb.pop();

                    if (jsonMap.find(key) != jsonMap.end())
                        jsonMap[key] = jsonMap[key] + "," + value;
                    else
                        jsonMap.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
                }
                else
                {
                    if (ret == MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS)
                    {
                        str = "{";
                        for (auto itr = jsonMap.begin(); itr != jsonMap.end(); ++itr) {
                            str += itr->first + "\n" + "\t\t{" + itr->second + "},\n";
                        }
                        str = str.substr(0, str.length() - 2);
                        str += "}";
                    }
                    LOGMESSAGE("data..." << str << std::endl);
                    LOGMESSAGE("length " << str.length() << std::endl);

                    /*Some stuff*/
                }
            }
        }
    }

int main()
{
    handle_incoming_message();
    sendData();
    return 0;
}
```

The error is coming in line below while accessing the front element:

```
data += App::Instance->haraldMsgDb.front();
```

As I am popping the data from the queue, hence I am checking if the queue is not empty before accessing the front() of queue. but still getting the error.

When I am debugging thoroughly, the error is coming in deque file of Visual Studio:

```
    reference operator*() const
            {   // return designated object
            const auto _Mycont = static_cast<const _Mydeque *>(this->_Getcont());
     #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
            if (_Mycont == 0
                || this->_Myoff < _Mycont->_Myoff
                || _Mycont->_Myoff + _Mycont->_Mysize <= this->_Myoff)
            {   // report error
            _DEBUG_ERROR("deque iterator not dereferencable");
            }
```

Here, `_Mycont` is getting null/zero, which is upfront throwing this exception. Could anyone let me know why I am getting this error?

Comment: It seems that you are calling `empty` and `front` on different objects: `TimeSeriesApp::TimeSeriesAppInstance->haraldMsgDb` vs `App::Instance->haraldMsgDb`. But without knowing how these identifiers are declared, it is impossible to be sure.

Comment: sry my bad, empty is also called on App::Instance->haraldMsgDb only. It was just the typo error. and regarding the declaration, It is defined in header  file as -
std::queue<std::string> haraldMsgDb